# Outlook removes To-Do bar whenever switching from E-Mail to Calendar back to E-Mail view

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, multiple-monitors, calendar

I am having troubles identifying the cause and/or the soloution to the following scenario.

I am running Outlook on a vertical monitor. Whenever I am switching from the "E-Mail" view to the "Calendar" view back to the "E-Mail" view, the To-Do bar disappears. I then have to manually re-enable the To-Do bar every time I switch from the E-Mail view to the Calendar view and back. A step to step guide can be found below.

[E-Mail View with To-Do Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP9g5.png)

[Switching from E-Mail to Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIoKJ.png)

[Calendar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Qd9.png)

[E-Mail View but you have to enable the To-Do bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Gne.png)

If the monitor is horizontal, the above explained can be performed normally and without errors.
However, this view previously worked without problems on the same monitor and has done so for several years.
I've already installed every available Windows Update & every possible driver update.

Comment: I can't replicate this using the full-fat Outlook desktop app `v16.0.13801.20960`. Which version are you running?

Comment: I'm running `v16.0.014326.20384`. I'm going to update the Outlook app and try to replicate the issue afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshots you provided, I noticed that the People view is displayed in the "Calendar view" screenshot. I conducted both the two tests in my outlook 365 client (version below), but didn't reproduce your issue.

- "E-Mail" view to the "Calendar" view back to the "E-Mail" view
- "E-Mail" view to the "People" view back to the "E-Mail" view

[image]

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Hope the above!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.